Antenna design for A7672 module by SimCom
I am working on a project which is a PCB for the SimCom's A7672 GNSS+LTE+BLE module. The A7672 module has the capability of GNSS, LTE and BLE.
My question is that I am designing a custom board for an automotive environment, here all the 3 antennas for GNSS, LTE and BLE will be externally connected through a SMA connector. The question is: while adding a SMA connector on my board, I wanted to do impedance matching of 50 Ω (I am new to RF PCB design).
During my research, I found that to impedance match an RF Tx Line, I need to add a pi-network like this:

The refence design guide can be found here:
https://en.simcom.com/product/A7672X.html
(In the link above I followed the A7672X_A7670X_Series_Hardware_Design_V1.03.pdf file(You will need to login before you download... if you have another suggestion regarding how to directly paste the document please do let me know)
My doubts are:

how do I select the values for the capacitors and inductor in the matching circuit.

I came across AppCAD software to calculate trace width and other PCB properties to calculate exact PCB trace width for the Tx line to the antenna. Do I need the match circuit in this case? If no, how do I calculate the matching circuit component values given the trace width from the AppCAD software?


Note: The antenna will be an external one. I will give a provision for the antenna to be connected (SMA connector).
I am new to RF PCB design. Any help is highly appreciated.

Vatsal245 - Hi, Which document did you screenshot? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name and its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, edition etc. TY (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].)

Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. i will edit and povide the link to the document
